# systemctl Failed to start service, Invalid argument

Tags: linux, command-line, systemctl

I need to run a Qt application on startup with root permission , below is the script I created using systemctl named `QtApp.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=QtApp

[Service]
ExecStart= exec su -l user -c 'export DISPLAY=:0; /QtInst/QtApp'
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I run the command to start the service `sudo systemctl start QtApp.service` I am getting following error

```
Failed to start QtApp.service: Unit QtApp.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
```

Here is the details of error

```
systemctl status QtApp.service
● QtApp.service - QtApp
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Jul 06 15:23:54 user-pc systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/QtApp.service:5] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: exec su -l user -c 'export DISPLAY=:0; /QtInst/QtApp'
Jul 06 15:23:54 user-pc systemd[1]: QtApp.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Jul 06 15:26:08 user-pc systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/QtApp.service:5] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: exec su -l user -c 'export DISPLAY=:0; /QtInst/QtApp'
Jul 06 15:26:08 user-pc systemd[1]: QtApp.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Executable path is not absolute` -- it means `exec`.

Generally `exec` makes no sense here. It's a shell builtin that replaces the shell with a given command. There is no absolute path to `exec` executable because there is no executable.

`su` *is* an executable. The line may be

```
ExecStart=/bin/su -l user -c 'export DISPLAY=:0; /QtInst/QtApp'
```

**But** using `su` may not be a good idea in systemd service. See: [*How do I make my systemd service run via specific user and start on boot?*](https://askubuntu.com/q/676007/693277)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the "Invalid argument" here is the unit definition file itself. To debug it you can use:

```
sudo systemd-analyze verify QtApp.service
```

or in case of user's local service:

```
sudo systemd-analyze --user verify QtApp.service
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says

```
Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: exec su -l user -c 'export DISPLAY=:0; /QtInst/QtApp'
```

Try to use the absolut path (e.g. */usr/local/QtInst/QtApp*) instead of */QtInst/QtApp*.

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395131/systemd-service-lacks-both-execstart-and-execstop-setting-refusing/395133#395133) might be relevant.

Comment: Actually the executable is in the folder in `/QtInst/`

Comment: Have you tried to delete the space after ExecStart= ? and set it in quotes, ExecStart="exec su -l user -c 'export DISPLAY=:0; /QtInst/QtApp'"

Comment: No, I will try it